# EJS to Handlebars conversion - sails-hook-flash

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, sails.js

I am using the sails hook sails-hook-flash

The example using EJS is thus

```
<% flash.get('success').forEach(function (message) { %>
<div class="alert alert-success">
   <%= message %>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to see how this could be done with handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
{{ #each flash.get('success') }}
<div class="alert alert-success">
   {{this}}
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
</div>
{{ /each }}
```